# Twisted transport.write and irregular prefixes

Tags: python, unicode, twisted

Does transport.write need a non-printable prefix to run?

Basically, sending over a test json object from a pyqt test client.
Object sent boils down to:

```
message = {"key": "Value"}
self.client.send_msg(pyjson5.encode(message).encode("utf-8"))
```

and this is received on the server side as (in raw byte form):

```
b'\x0f\x00\x00\x00{"key":"Value"}'
```

Now, if I were to assign the above to variable *data*, and tried to return, it works fine

```
transport.write(data)
```

But, if I were to clean off the leading non printable chars, via.

```
data2 = data.decode("utf-8")

remove_strings = ["\x0f", "\x10", "\x00"]
for rm_string in remove_strings:
    data2 = data2.strip(rm_string)
```

At this point, data2 is a string:

```
{"key":"Value"}
```

---

edit2: Following from snakecharmerb's comment; Just to clarify - at this point I can then decode the JSON object into a dictionary and use it as such.

---

If I then tried to return it to a byte form and resend, i.e.

```
transport.write(data2.encode("utf-8")
```

It silently fails to send.

Any ideas? Why does send_msg work fine without the leading non-printable, yet transport.write refuses?

edit: Probably using unicode incorrectly, so amended.

Comment: Because I can't decode the json object with them present.... after stripping them out, the json decodes fine.

Comment: For the benefit of anyone else reading this, it looks like I'll go down the route of RPyC - not really an answer to my question, but may lead others to a solution that works for them.

Comment: No, transport.write doesn't need any particular bytes.  It will send any bytes.  Wherever the problem is in your program, it's somewhere else.  It looks to me like your 4 byte prefix is a length prefix - presumably added by `self.client.send_msg`, whatever that is, and when you try to send messages with no length prefix, the peer interprets them as though they have one and then waits for the few million bytes that interpretation suggests it should expect.  This is mostly guesswork though, since the question does not include enough details to really know what's going on.

Comment: Hi Jean-Paul; the code above unfortunately is pretty much my test - I've reduced it that far seeking enlightment! b'\x0f\x00\x00\x00{"key":"Value"}' will send via transport.write, whereas b'{"key":"Value"}' won't.  If transport.write requires the length prefix and self.client.send_msg doesn't, it suggests there is a means of having twisted automatically determine the length and send - in which case do you (or anyone else) know the syntax to enable that please?

Comment: `transport.write` *will* send `b'{"key":"Value"}'`.  Find a different way to observe it (use nc on the other end, use tcpdump, etc) so you can see this happen.